# OpenGL/GLSL checking if shader compiled fine on intel cards

Tags: opengl, intel, glsl

i am using this code to check if my glsl shader compiled fine.

```
    glGetObjectParameterivARB(obj, GL_OBJECT_INFO_LOG_LENGTH_ARB, &infologLength);

    if (infologLength > 1)
    {
        int charsWritten  = 0;
        char * const infoLog = new char[infologLength];
        glGetInfoLogARB(obj, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog);
        tError(infoLog, false);
        delete infoLog;
    }
}
```

the length of the returned string is empty on nvidia and ATI cards, but on intel cards this one returns the string "no errors."

now what is the best way to find out, if there are really no errors? should i just check for this string? or is there a convention what this function glGetInfoLogARB should return?

Comment: glGetInfoLogARB is to be used for debugging purposes only, so no, there's no standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
bool CompileSuccessful(int obj) {
  int status;
  glGetShaderiv(obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
  return status == GL_TRUE;
}
```

to check if a shader was compiled successfully and

```
bool LinkSuccessful(int obj) {
  int status;
  glGetProgramiv(obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
  return status == GL_TRUE;
}
```

to check if the whole program was linked successfully.

Comment: thanks but it seems it doesnt work on my intel card. the value of status isnt changed at all.

Comment: Does your intel card support the necessary extensions to use shaders?